# Mac Monterrey HDMI cable blue screen on external monitor

Tags: display, hdmi

I have a MacBook Air M1 2020 with Monterrey OS, a Startech HDMI adapter and a HDMI cable.

When I plug it in to external monitors it works.
When I plug the Mac with this setup to TVs it doesn't work. As soon as I plug I see the screen being extended for 1 second and then everything turns blue.
The screen is correctly detected. I try to play with all the settings but nothing happens.
If I try with another Mac I have the result is the same.
If I try the cable with other laptop on other monitors it works.
I am not sure what is the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Which Startech adapter? What brand(s) of TV? Q: the connection to _any_ TV through an HDMI port using the adapter fails? Are you testing on _one_ TV or several? Since the connection to TV(s) using _another_ laptop also fails, I'd hazard a guess the adapter is at fault. I use [this adapter from Anker](https://www.amazon.com/Anker-Aluminum-Pixelbook-Compatible-Thunderbolt/dp/B07THJGZ9Z) to connect a variety of MacBooks & Chromebooks to large Samsung LCD commercial signage screens. I used my 2019 MBP as a test device on 12 screens during deployment over the summer. It is only US$18.